# $\Phi : \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an Injective application

Tags: group-theory

Let m and n be distinct prime numbers greater that 1. I am trying to show that the following application in an isomorphism:

$\Phi : \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

- In order to show that it is an isomorphism I want to show that it is bijective (surjective and injective).
  I had no problem showing that it was surjective but **I'm having trouble with the proof of its injectivity.**
- **Another idea I had** was to just say that $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ has $mn$ element and so does $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ Therefore $\Phi : \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is bijective

Comment: This is false, if $n$ and $m$ are not distinct primes (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). Is this one of your hypotheses? In any event, supposing it is, any surjective map between finite sets of the same cardinality is also a bijection. If you're bent on showing injectivity directly, note that any equivalence class mod $nm$ which reduces to $0$ mod $m$ and mod $n$ has representative divisible by both $n$ and $m$, whence it is divisible by $\mathrm{lcm}(n,m) = nm$. (This step breaks down if $n = m$, of course.)

Comment: You haven't actually given an application – you haven't told us how to compute $\Phi$. Obviously, if $\Phi(x)=0$ for all $x$, then it's not injective.

Answer (score 0):

As Gerry Myerson pointed out, you didn't define an application. I suppose you're looking for the **chinese remainder theorem** :

If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then the (well defined) map
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\Phi : & \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \\
\phantom{\phi :} & x \operatorname{mod} mn \mapsto (x\operatorname{mod} m, x \operatorname{mod} n) 
\end{array}$$
is an isomorphism.